# How to check if document exists in lucene index?

Tags: lucene

I have an index of news articles, where i save title,link,description of news.. sometimes its possible that same news from same link is published with different titles by different news sources. it don't want exactly same description articles to be added twice..how to find if document already exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with Java.
Assuming your link is being saved in the index as a StringField (so any analyzers you use won't break up the link into multiple terms), you can use a TermQuery.

```java
TopDocs results = searcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("link", "http://example.com")), 1);
if (results.totalHits == 0){
    Document doc = new Document();
    // create your document here with your fields
    // link field should be stored as a StringField
    doc.add(new StringField("link", "http://example.com", Stored.YES));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

Note that StringFields are stored exactly so you may want to convert to lowercase when searching/indexing.

If you wish to make sure not more than 1 field already exists, then you can run it as a BooleanQuery using the Occur.SHOULD condition:

```java
BooleanQuery matchingQuery = new BooleanQuery();
matchingQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("link", "http://example.com")), Occur.SHOULD);
matchingQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("description", "the unique description of the article")), Occur.SHOULD);
TopDocs results = searcher.search(matchingQuery, 1);
if (results.totalHits == 0){
    Document doc = new Document();
    // create your document here with your fields
    // link field should be stored as a StringField
    doc.add(new StringField("link", "http://example.com", Stored.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("description", "the unique description of the article", Stored.YES));
    // note if you need the description to be tokenized, you need to add another TextField to the document with a different field name
    doc.add(new TextField("descriptionText", "the unique description of the article", Stored.NO));

    writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

Comment: I am still facing issues.. it seems same articles are posted on different newspaper with different links.. so in addition to link, I need another field as the primary field.. in order to avoid multiple search results to same article on different newspaper sites.. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you tell that each article is the same? The description? If so, then you can use the description as your uniquely identifying field.

Comment: yes through description.. but i want to avoid 2 kinds of duplicates in my index,. articles with same description and same link.. cause they ultimately point to same data.. so how to have 2 unique identifiers?

Comment: @Sneha I updated the answer so it prevents duplicates on 2 fields.